# MySQL VARCHAR like Data type with MIN and MAX character lengths

Tags: mysql, validation, database-design, types

Looking for a data type that is similar to VARCHAR as to the values I would like, but is there a way to have a MIN/MAX character length?

```
VARCHAR(6,10)
```

This would have a minimum of 6 characters and a maximum of 10 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a trigger to throw an exception when the values are outside of the range, e.g.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `insert_table_var` BEFORE INSERT ON `table` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     DECLARE str_len INT DEFAULT 0;
     DECLARE max_len INT DEFAULT 10;
     DECLARE min_len INT DEFAULT 6;

     SET str_len = LENGTH(NEW.col);

     IF str_len > max_len OR str_len < min_len 
     THEN
           CALL col_length_outside_range_error();
     END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;;
```

Whilst SIGNAL is not available, calling an undefined stored procedure would suffice (in this case `col_length_outside_range_error`). Otherwise, I think that the application using the database is going to need to do the checks.

Answer (score 2):

This is called CHECK constraint in SQL and it is [ignored by MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html).

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

Comment: So something like this:  CHECK (LENGTH(fieldName) >= 6 AND LENGTH(fieldName) <= 10)

Comment: @Phill Pafford: do you not need this for MySQL?

Comment: @Phil This answer doesn't work in MySQL though, so your constraints aren't enforced in the database

Comment: Check constraints should work from version 8.0.16: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html