# MySQL char accepts values which are not fixed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, constraints

I still can't able to figured out why is this. Below is my SQL syntax..

```
create table usertbl{
    id int auto_increment,
    name varchar(30) not null,
    cupon_code char(10) not null,
    primary key(id)
}
```

So according to this table, the `cupon_code` field has a fixed length, but when I insert data to that field without a fixed value, like `we3434`, it gets accepted.

I want the table to reject values for `cupon_code` field if the value is less than 10 or greater than 10. It always has to be fixed with 10 characters. So can I know why is this? and how can I avoid this issue?

Comment: `char(10)` means that the rest will be filled with spaces. You can add a trigger that checks the value before inserting.

Comment: In `Char(X)` and `VARCHAR(X)` X denotes the maximum length. The only difference is that `CHAR(X)` will always allocate X characters of space on the table while `VARCHAR(X)` will allocate as many characters as it needs (plus a length indicator). It's not a constraint on minimum length

Comment: You are probably better checking this in your HTML rather than relying on the database.

Comment: Can I avoid the spaces? I mean I don't want spaces to be inserted.

Comment: If your only ever going to be inserting 10 char fields, then there will be no extra spaces added as it will fill the field.

Comment: To avoid the spaces, use varchar instead of char.

Comment: I think you just need to validate your data before you insert it

Comment: @SloanThrasher can I know what is the use of using CHAR then?

Comment: @juergend but when I retrieve data from that column, there is not spaces contain with the value

Comment: @juergend Can you show me an example on how to use a trigger at this case?

Comment: You could write a function or trigger to validate before inserting.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Can you show me an example on how to use a trigger at this case?

Comment: @SaraRobert Check the original mySQL Docs. There are plenty examples: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: VARCHAR stores a string plus a length meaning that if you know that you need to store strings of length exactly X (e.g. when storing GUIDs) CHAR is better because it stores exactly what it needs without storing the length of each string. Also if you only have fixed width columns in your table you might take advantage of faster random access but that is DBMS dependent.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a constraint on `MIN` with mysql and the `CHAR(x)` only force the max length.

Using [MySQL VARCHAR like Data type with MIN and MAX character lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834330/mysql-varchar-like-data-type-with-min-and-max-character-lengths) you can make the following trigger :

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `tgi_usertbl_cupon_code_length` BEFORE INSERT ON `usertbl` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    IF LENGTH(NEW.cupon_code) <> 10
    THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'ERROR - Invalid length of cupon_code';
    END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `DELIMITER ;;` should be `DELIMITER ;` and you can reduce the `if` to `LENGTH(NEW.cupon_code) <> 10`

Answer (score 0):

You can use where condition while inserting data like

```
Insert into tablename (column name) values (values) where len(columnname) <= 10
```

Even though you got the answer may you can get some idea

Comment: Is this method practically good? Can I use this for projects instead of triggers?

Comment: I have tried. Just try this if you got the expected output use this or else you can go for trigger method.